# Forcing child to obey parent's curved borders in CSS

Tags: css

I have a div inside of another div.  `#outer` and `#inner`.  `#outer` has curved borders and a white background.  `#inner` has no curved borders and a green background.  `#inner` extends beyond the curved borders of `#outer`.  Is there anyway to stop this?

```css
#outer {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#inner {
  background-color: #209400;
  height: 10px;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
  <!-- other stuff needs a white background -->
  <!-- bottom corners needs a white background -->
</div>
```

No matter how I try it still overlaps.  How can I make `#inner` obey and fill to `#outer`'s  borders?

**edit**

The following hack served the purpose for now.  But the question stands (maybe to the CSS3 and webbrowser writers): **Why don't child elements obey their parent's curved borders and is there anyway to force them to?**

The hack to get around this for my needs for now, you can assign curves to individual borders.  So for my purposes, I just assigned a curve to the top two of the inner element.

```
#inner {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to set exactly the same border radius to the internal element?

Comment: But I want the border radius of the internal element to be straight on the bottom.  Is it possible to set a border radius just for a certain corner?

Comment: For sure. You can even assign them like `border-radius: TL TR BL BR`.

Comment: I read this as "Forcing child to obey parent's orders". :)

Comment: With the exception of Safari, `-moz-border-radius` and `border-radius` can be used as a shorthand with four values: `10px 10px 0 0`. For Safari however you need to set them individually.

Answer (score 347, accepted):

According to the specs:

> A box's backgrounds, but not its
>   border-image, are clipped to the
>   appropriate curve (as determined by
>   ‘background-clip’). Other effects that
>   clip to the border or padding edge
>   (such as ‘overflow’ other than
>   ‘visible’) also must clip to the
>   curve. **The content of replaced
>   elements is always trimmed to the
>   content edge curve.** Also, the area
>   outside the curve of the border edge
>   does not accept mouse events on behalf
>   of the element.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius

This means that an `overflow: hidden` on `#outer` should work. However, this won't work for Firefox 3.6 and below. This is fixed in Firefox 4:

> Rounded corners now clip content and images (if  overflow: visible  is not set).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-border-radius

So you'll still need the fix, just shorten it to:

```
#outer {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#inner {
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

**See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/VaTAZ/3/**

Comment: Bingo, I was testing with Firefox 3.6.  So this explains it.

Comment: Anyone coming in this late in the game, `overflow: hidden;` is working on current versions of FF. Make sure you test back as far as your requirements need.

Comment: Just wanna note that the fiddle has margin, so the real effect of `overflow hidden` is hidden

Comment: What if we don't want the overflow content to be hidden? A hidden overflow will cut off things like tooltip popups and window menus that appear inside.

Comment: Just add overflow: hidden; and border-radius to outer DIV

Comment: Your answer is still helping people in 2021. @Yi Jiang. Thank you!

Comment: Godsent! this worked!!

Comment: Well I'm using **Firefox 106** now and `overflow` works perfectly. :D

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use

> border-radius: inherit;

to follow the parent

```css
.parent {
 width: 100px;
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid green;
 border-radius: 16px 16px 0 0;
 padding: 10px;
}
.child {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: in case for some reason you can't use 'overflow:hidden' on the parent, this is the way to go

Comment: This does not play well with pseudo attrs like `::after`

Answer (score 2):

What would be wrong with this?

```
#outer { 
    display: block; float: right; margin: 0; width: 200px;
    background-color: white; overflow: hidden;
}
#inner { background-color: #209400; height: 10px; border-top: none; }

#outer, #inner{
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: I want the bottom to be sharp cornered.  This would take two inner divs, one given a negative margin to overlap the other.

Comment: Hmm... turns out you can set individual corners.  So I just set the top two.

Answer (score 1):

If you want sharp edges on the bottom:
Use these :

```
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px; 

-moz-border-radius-topleft
-moz-border-radius-topright
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried making the position:relative for the inner div ???

that is:

```
#inner { 
    background-color: #209400; 
    height: 10px; 
    border-top: none; 
    position: relative; 
    left: 15px; 
    top: 15px; 
}
```

Comment: Using `position: relative` doesn't work :/