# background reverses border-radius

Tags: background, sass, css

Why reverses a `background` property of a lower element the `border-radius` set on a higher element?

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="header">Title</div>
        <div class="form"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS code:

```
.wrapper {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    height: 250px;
    left: 100px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 10000

    .header {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #444444;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
}
```

The result is that there is no `border-radius` at the top, just at the bottom. If I remove the `background` property of the `.header`class the `border-radius` works on all four sides. What is the problem here?

Comment: ur present code shows border-radius..

Comment: first)there is a problem with braces in css.

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting a selector inside other, which is wrong.
Try this.

```
.wrapper {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    height: 250px;
    left: 100px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 10000
}
    .header {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #444444;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

this must work, 
and if you apply any background color on any of the child div then you have to explicitly set its corner radius..

Comment: Thank you! But I don't understand this behaviour. Why does it work this way?

Comment: its simple you can not place a css selector inside other css selector.

Comment: Errr, yes I can if I write SCSS. I meant why do I have to set the `border-radius` again for child elements which have a `background` property?

Comment: this is becoz the childs will then cover the radius of parent container which will no longer visible as rounded, even if u set parents overflow hidden. so this is the one solution to make childs that corner rounded. you can try experiment with this,

Comment: Ok here is detailed explanation of this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714862/forcing-child-to-obey-parents-curved-borders-in-css

Answer (score 0):

Check this

http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/LtRUu/

```
.wrapper {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    height: 250px;
    left: 100px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 10000;
    color:red;
}
    .header {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #444444;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```