# Why is the border radius of the element on the back visible?

Tags: html, css

I have two elements: `article` (which is in the back) and `header` which is in the front:

```css
article[_v-e514def2] {      
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #2a2721;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
    
article header[_v-e514def2] {
    background-color: #484a47;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<article _v-e514def2="">
    <header _v-e514def2="">
        <h3 _v-e514def2="">Hardcoded Title</h3>
    </header>
    <section _v-e514def2="">
        <p>...</p>
    </section>
</article>
```

As you can see they have the same border radius. However, you can see the border of the element on the back:

[image]

Is this normal? If so, what's the easiest workaround?

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kykrx5t5/).

Comment: Have you tried adding `z-index: 1;` or `z-index: 1000;` for your article definition of css?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing child to obey parent's curved borders in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714862/forcing-child-to-obey-parents-curved-borders-in-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you two solutions:

[DEMO 1](http://output.jsbin.com/bobesowopu)

Put a `margin-top: -1px;` on:

CSS

```
article header[_v-e514def2] {
  background-color: #484a47;
  padding: 5px 0;  
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

[DEMO 2](http://output.jsbin.com/bofifujidu/1)

Increase `border-radius: 5px 3px;` on:

CSS

```
article[_v-e514def2] {
   background-color: #fff;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #2a2721;
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 10px;
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   border-radius: 5px 3px;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So this is a normal CSS rendering behavior?

Comment: `:)` I thinks so.. Vucko has given you a good link with the specs.